# Composer says class does not comply with psr-4 autoloading, but the code works anyway

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

The class Test, in MyApp\src\models folder:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Models;

class Test 
{

    function __construct() {
        echo "class Test running...";
    }

}
```

The index page on project root:

```
<?php

require_once realpath("vendor/autoload.php");

use MyApp\Models\Test;

$test = new Test();
```

But when I run the command:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

The error message says:

```
MyApp/src\models\Test.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```

But it generates vendor folder with autoload.php and other files anyway. And index.php works fine. So what I am missing here?

Comment: have you tried deleting the vendors folder and running composer again? sometimes leftovers cause issues... I think that your issue is that the path is `MyApp\src\models` but your class is in  namespace `MyApp\Models` - you need to ensure that your case is correct and path matches the namespace (and follows PSR-4 standard)

Comment: Yes, I deleted vendor folder, and after running composer again gave me the same error message. What psr-4 rules I'm not following with this simple PHP class?

Comment: as I remember the case has to be either all-lower in the path or capitalized. that it works is probably because you are using an NTFS or FAT os where case is insensitive. I have had a lot of issues with changing case to fix case sensitive paths in a linux server (after coding on a windows machine) - read 2.6 here: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ - and that seems to be that the namespace and any subnamespaces must start with a capital - so your issue is the path is lowercase, and therefore not compliant. Be careful if you have already committed this code to git!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the spec](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), you need to have your namespace path in FirstCaps.

Your path is lowercase `MyApp\src\models` but your namespace is FirstCap:

```php
<?php
namespace MyApp\Models;
```

if you rename your folder to `MyApp\src\Models` you should be good to go.

If you have already committed your code to git, and are on a windows PC be aware that since both NTFS and FAT filesystems are case insensitive, you may experience issues jsut renaming the folder from `models` to `Models`. You may have to rename from `models` to `somethingelse` (and commit) and then rename to `Models` (and commit again)